# no results in inserting values to MySQL with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

on my research site, I have a few radio buttons and I want to send their values to MySQL table using jquery and AJAX. All buttons and jquery code are put in **single-project.php** (I modified WordPress theme) and the bits of code that should handle interaction with the MySQL are put in the **db.php** in the same folder.

However, something is not in order, because values do not appear on the database table. Could someone help?

**jquery:**

```
      //the last button
        $('#submit_last_button').click(function(){
        SomeVariable = $('input:radio[name=lastRadio]:checked').val();
             if (!$("input:radio[name=lastRadio]").is(":checked")) {
              $("label#lastRadio_error").show();
              $("input#lastRadio").focus();
              return false;
            } else {
            if ('input:radio[name=lastRadio]:checked')
            $('#PreviousButtonDiv').hide();
            $('#NextDiv').show();
            $.post('db.php',{action: "submit_last_button", previous_variable:SomePreviousVariable, last_variable:SomeVariable},function(res){
            $('#result').html(res);
            });
            }
          });
        });
```

**db.php:**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','user', 'password');
$db     = mysql_select_db('my_database');

if($_POST['action'] == 'submit_last_button'){

    $previous_variable  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['previous_variable']);
    $last_variable = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last_variable']);




    $sql   = "insert into MyTable (id, variable1, variable2) values ( NULL, '$previous_variable', '$last_variable')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if($query){
        echo "Record Inserted.";
    }else {
        echo "Something Wrong!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you debugged the Javascript variables before the AJAX action to make sure they contain what you expect?

Comment: Have you tried to debug at all to narrow down the source of the problem? For example, is the POST request being properly constructed or is the problem with the server-side script?  Some very basic debugging will narrow this problem down fast.

Comment: @scrowler - yes, I used alert to check if they contain what I expect them to contain, and no problem there

Comment: @MikeBrant - ehm, no, debugging is a sphere beyond my knowledge. What should I do?

Comment: OK - in PHP try `var_dump($_POST);` then make sure your variables are making it to your PHP script correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There are various possibilities of what is not working on your code. But first, the problem is not in AJAX not saving on MySQL. AJAX is passing your data to the php script on your server to then, save it on MySQL.

1. Check if the values are reaching your script correctly;
2. Check if you're getting a db connection - check error logs or print them out;
3. Check if you're not getting a SQL syntax erro - again, check for logs;
4. Check if auto-commit is true (it is by default).